# How to solve $y'+2xy=2x^3y^3$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $$y'+2xy=2x^3y^3$$

Would I just do $y'=2x^3y^3-2xy$ and integrate?

Comment: is this not a bernoulli equation? try change of variable $y = u^k$ first.

Answer (score 1):

we will make a change of variable $$y = u^k, y' = ku^{k-1}u'  $$ this turns $y+2xy = 2x^3y^3$ into $$ku^{k-1}u' + 2xu^k = 2x^3u^{3k}$$ now choose $k = -1/2$ so that 
$$-1/2u^{-3/2}u' + 2xu^{-1/2}=2x^3u^{-3/2} \to u' - 4xu=-4x^3 $$ this is a linear non homogeneous equation that can be solved in different ways. i hope you can take it from here. if you need help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be the solution ?

[image]

I'm OP

Comment: yes, you are right. you are two people?

Comment: I am actually an infinite amount of people. Thank you so much for your help abel :)

Comment: you are welcome stan. good luck with the differential equations. it can be fun finding ways to solve these. practice makes it a little bit easier to see the change of variables etc.